# Amplify high and low value damper

Tags: java, statistics

I have a formula which calculates a measure based on a set of numerical attributes. This formula outputs a number between 0 and 1.
I also have a sort of damper value that I use. This damper value is also computed based on some attributes I use, this damper value is another number between 0 and 1.
The way I'd like it to work is that the number produced by the formula is decreased by the damper value if the damper value is close to 1 or close to 0. However if the damper value is to 0.5 then number produced by the formula would be increased by the damper value.
I hope this makes sense,
Regards.

Comment: This sounds more like a math problem than a programming problem. You might want to review [ask]. I don't think your question is clear enough for this site the way it's written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make use of the sine function?  When using radians, if you multiply your damping value by Pi, you can then put that value through sine and subtract 0.5d from its returned value like so:

```
double dampening = (funcToComputeDampening()*Math.PI);
double valueToAdjustOutputWith = Math.sin(dampening)-0.5d;
double outputWithDampening = output + valueToAdjustOutputWith;
```

Comment: @GreenApples53 If this worked for you, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark :)